# Unfortunately app stopped on AVD in android

Tags: java, android, string, casting, android-edittext

I am trying to build a simple calculator app having:

3 `EditText` for 2 numbers and for result.

6 `Buttons` + - * / = clear.

When running this app on the AVD it is flashing "Unfortunately app stopped!"

That means there would be some sort of exception being encountered but i am not able to understand what.

When i checked on Logcat, there was something *"EditText cannot be typecast to String"*.

Please help me out to debug this exception.

```
package com.example.calci_ver1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button badd, bsub, bmul, bdiv, beq, bclr;
static EditText et1, et2, et3;

static int i=0, n1, n2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    badd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bsub = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    bmul = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    bdiv = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    beq = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    bclr = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);

    et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    et3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    badd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i = 1;
        }
    });

    bsub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i = 2;
        }
    });

    bmul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i = 3;
        }
    });

    bdiv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i = 4;
        }
    });

    beq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            String s1, s2;

            s1 = et1.getText().toString();
            s2 = et2.getText().toString();

            n1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
            n2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);

            calculation();

            i = 0;
        }
    });

    bclr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            et1.setText("");
            et2.setText("");
            et3.setText("");
        }
    });
}

public static void calculation() {

    switch(i)
    {
        case 1: et3.setText(n1+n2);
        break;

        case 2: et3.setText(n1-n2);
        break;

        case 3: et3.setText(n1*n2);
        break;

        case 4: et3.setText(n1/n2);
        break;
    }
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Try my answer it might help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found problem that may cause application crash..

Remove the code what you written in `calculation()` method.

Actually your problem is that you pass the result of two numbers its give the numeric value and `android` has method on `edittext` `setText(int resid)` so its means its searching text of resid in `string.xml` which is not present. So its crashing your application. So you need to convert the result in `String`.

Use this.

```
public static void calculation() {

    switch(i)
    {
        double result = 0;
        case 1: 
            result = n1+n2;
            et3.setText(String.valueOf(result));
        break;

        case 2: 
            result = n1-n2;
            et3.setText(String.valueOf(result));
        break;

        case 3: 
            result = n1*n2;
            et3.setText(String.valueOf(result));
        break;

        case 4: 
            result = n1/n2;
            et3.setText(String.valueOf(result));
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: yep..u were ryt...i didn't parse that to String. thanks for the help...:-) and i accepted your answer as well.

Comment: please also guide me with one more thing that if i want to calculate the answer for a string provided in the edittext then how can i do so? like "30+5*4/7-8"... please consider the BODMAS rule as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've found AVD occasionally throws those errors when you call a `.setText()` command, I have never encountered the error on a real life device though, so just reinstall the program on your AVD.  I'll look around a bit because I had this problem and I know I have seen it on SO before.

Comment: how to re-install on AVD? i have tried restarting it as well with "wipe user data" but still not working.

Comment: or please tell me some alternative to do the same task?

Comment: Just uninstall your app under the apps tab and rerun it using eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Use 
android:inputType="number"
 to force it to be numeric.

Convert the resulting string into an integer (e.g., Integer.parseInt(myEditText.getText().toString())).